# ERROR at line 5: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I have two related tables. I'm creating them in the following order, which I'm almost sure is correct. The problem is that I'm unable to create first table "vod_classification" because I'm receiving an error:

> ERROR at line 5:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
CREATE TABLE vod_classification (
dbClassId CHAR(4),
dbDescription VARCHAR2(90),
CONSTRAINT vod_classification_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbClassId),
REFERENCES vod_film (dbClass)
);

CREATE TABLE vod_film (
dbFilmId               NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
dbTitle                VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
dbDirector_firstname   VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
dbDirector_lastname    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
dbGenre                VARCHAR2(10),
dbUK_release_date      DATE,
dbFilename             VARCHAR2 (15),
dbRuntime              NUMBER (10),
dbClass                CHAR(8),
CONSTRAINT vod_film_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbFilmId),
CONSTRAINT vod_film_class_FK
FOREIGN KEY (dbClass)
REFERENCES vod_classification (dbClassId)
ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`PRIMARY KEY`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) does not have `REFERENCES` part:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE vod_classification (
dbClassId CHAR(4),
dbDescription VARCHAR2(90),
CONSTRAINT vod_classification_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbClassId)
--REFERENCES vod_film (dbClass)
);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7a3f8301e253f166271c2795bc9602d3)**

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong, but the question is *what*.

It is easy to remove the REFERENCES clause from the VOD_CLASSIFICATION table if it doesn't belong there. However, it appears that you intentionally put it as PRIMARY KEY constraint ends with a comma, so it *might* mean that you really meant to create a foreign key from the VOD_CLASSIFICATION table to VOD_FILM.

If that's so, you should switch places for those two tables because you can't create a foreign key constraint which references a table that hasn't been created yet.

On the other hand, VOD_FILM also references the VOD_CLASSIFICATION table. This is not a very usual situation, where two tables interchange foreign key constraints on the same column, i.e. both of them act as *masters* and *details*. Oracle will let you do that, but - column you reference should be primary or unique key (and VOD_FILM.DBCLASS is not). Moreover, foreign key constraints should be created using the ALTER TABLE commands.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table vod_classification
  2    (dbclassid     varchar2(4) constraint pk_class primary key,
  3     dbdescription varchar2(90)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create table vod_film
  2    (dbfilmid number (4), -- move PRIMARY KEY to DBCLASS constraint pk_film primary key,
  3     dbclass  varchar2(4) constraint pk_film primary key
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> alter table vod_classification add constraint
  2    fk_class_film foreign key (dbclassid)
  3    references vod_film (dbclass);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table vod_film add constraint
  2    fk_film_class foreign key (dbclass)
  3    references vod_classification (dbclassid);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

In such a case, you can't even drop tables (*detail* first, *master* next) as both of them are *master* and *detail*, so you'd have to drop foreign key constraints first, then the tables.

Is it what you really want? I don't think so.

Therefore, I suppose that REFERENCE clause you used in VOD_CLASSIFICATION is just a mistake and you should remove it.

Furthermore, is there any reason for using CHAR data type? You'd rather use VARCHAR2.

Also, you should match data types in both tables; VOD_CLASSIFICATION.DBCLASSID is CHAR(**4**), while VOD_FILM.DBCLASS (which references the DBCLASSID) is CHAR(**8**).

I've tried to fix those *mistakes* so here's how you should have done it.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE vod_classification (
  2    dbClassId VARCHAR2(4)      CONSTRAINT pk_class PRIMARY KEY,
  3    dbDescription VARCHAR2(90)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE vod_film (
  2    dbFilmId               NUMBER(4) NOT NULL
  3                               CONSTRAINT pk_film PRIMARY KEY,
  4    dbTitle                VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  5    dbDirector_firstname   VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  6    dbDirector_lastname    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  7    dbGenre                VARCHAR2(10),
  8    dbUK_release_date      DATE,
  9    dbFilename             VARCHAR2 (15),
 10    dbRuntime              NUMBER (10),
 11    dbClassId              VARCHAR2(4)
 12                               CONSTRAINT fk_film_class
 13                                 REFERENCES vod_classification (dbclassid)
 14                                 ON DELETE SET NULL
 15  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

So much fuss about a pure, little ", REFERENCES vod_film (dbClass)" line ...

Comment: *" so it might mean that you really meant to create a foreign key"*. Yes but it's more likely to be a typo or a cut'n'paste error.

Comment: I agree; that's what I said in "Therefore, I suppose  ..." line :)